# Is there a way to Revert md5 hashed input?

Tags: php, html, webserver, md5, crypt

is it possible to decrypt a hash which is been generated with md5?

Example: I wanna develop a system which hash an input with md5.

Its gonna be a note system, so I wanna look up at the txt file which is doing this with `fopen()`.

The encrypting process is gonna doing this:

```
fwrite ( $handle, md5($input) );
```

The `$input` is `$_GET['message']`.

Can anyone help how to open a decrypted version of the note? best regards,

PS: The note system is for message exchanging, so It have to be reviewed by some other people.

Comment: BTW, it's "encrypt", not "crypt". A "crypt" is something else (e.g. Tales from the Crypt: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096708/ )

Answer (score 6):

No. MD5 is not an [encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) function, it's a [*hashing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) function. Hash functions are lossy. You can't go from a hash back to the original. That's why they're often used to store the hash of a password; you can store the hash without worrying that if your database is breached, you're giving out the passwords people have used. Having the *hash* of a password isn't all that useful to the attacker (whereas having the actual password would be, for trying it on other services, since people reuse them).

Answer (score 0):

No, Md5 is a **Hash** Function

in Mathematical point of view:

- **Encryption** Functions Are **Injective** (one-to-one) and can be **reverted** . so cypher can be deciphered.
- **Hash** Functions Are **non-Injective** (every output may have produced by multiple input) and cannot be **reverted**.